Divide a spreadsheet into separate files, based on the contents of first column
I have a spreadsheet consisting of 13 columns and just over 20,000 rows. It is arranged with column A in ascending order. Column A (DPK) has around 700 different values. I need to save a separate .xlsx file for each of the ~700 values, containing the header (2 rows), 13 columns and as many rows as apply to that column A value, which should also be the file name.

I searched around and found a few people who had done similar exercises, but none were exactly what I needed and they all seemed quite different from one another. I settled on one that seemed more simple (less variables for me to mess up), and tried to modify it for the  sample file (above), but I cannot get it to run.
So, the first DPK file (1000-2100.xlsx) should have the the header (I think I can sort this bit out), then 87 rows of data, the 2nd DPK (1001-2800.xlsx) should have the header, 22 rows of data, etc.
The best I have achieved is a Subscript out of range error. My knowledge of VBA is fairly limited (usually enough to have some idea of what is happening, but not enough to do anything from scratch etc) Any help is appreciated.
Sub Separate_book_to_sheets1()
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Dim DPK_book As Workbook
    Dim DPK_info, DPK_value As Range
    Dim DPK As String
    Set sht = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(ASCONS)
    Set DPK_info = sht.Range("A3:M347")
    sht.Range("A3:A347").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=sht.Range("A3:A347"), Unique:=True
    For Each DPK_value In sht.Range("A3:A347")
        DPK = DPK_value.Text
        Set DPK_book = Workbooks.Add
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="E:\Mike\Work\eCLIPSE\X\Projects\D0077 NEL\-Working\AsCons\DPKs\" & DPK & ".xlsx"
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        sht.Activate
        sht.AutoFilterMode = False
        DPK_info.AutoFilter field:=2, Criteria1:=DPK
        DPK_info.Copy
        DPK_book.Activate
        ActiveSheet.Paste
        ActiveWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=True
    Next DPK_value
End Sub


Mike

What is the value of ASCONS? Is there a worksheet called that? If not, you will get "subscript out of range"

(sorry) added .xlsx instead of .xlsm file. ASCONS is the name of Sheet1.

Then you need to put it in quotes: ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheets("ASCONS")

Thanks braX. That fixed the out of range error. Now I get the (ever uninformative) 400 error.

I really don't think that the question should have been closer. The OP is a new user that could not quite communicate as well as a seasoned used but I think it was quite obvious what he was asking for. "Don't bite a newbie".

Here is a slightly different approach, you can change the sheet names, ranges and files paths to suit you:
Sub FilterAndSave()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rngFilter As Range
    Dim uniqueValues As Collection
    Dim cell As Range
    Dim newWs As Worksheet
    Dim newWb As Workbook
    Dim value As Variant
    Dim filePath As String

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1") ' Change to your sheet name
    Set rng = ws.Range("A3").CurrentRegion ' Change to your range

    ' Get unique values from the column to filter
    Set uniqueValues = New Collection
    
    Set rngFilter = rng.Columns(1).Cells
    Set rngFilter = rngFilter.Offset(1, 0).Resize(rngFilter.Rows.Count - 1, rngFilter.Columns.Count)
    
    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell In rngFilter ' Change to the column you want to filter
        uniqueValues.Add cell.value, CStr(cell.value)
    Next cell
    On Error GoTo 0

    ' Loop through unique values and create new workbooks
    For Each value In uniqueValues
        ' Apply filter
        rng.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=value ' Change to the column you want to filter

        ' Create new workbook and copy filtered data
        Set newWb = Workbooks.Add
        Set newWs = newWb.Sheets(1)
        rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy Destination:=newWs.Range("A1")

        ' Save the new workbook
        filePath = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & value & ".xlsx"
        newWb.SaveAs filePath
        newWb.Close False
    Next value

    ' Clear filter
    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

    MsgBox "Filtered workbooks have been saved."
End Sub


Thanks Michal. I still have some editing to do on it, but I am a lot closer than I was before, thanks to you. Aside from your help, I don't really see any good reason to use this forum again, though. Thanks again.
